# Is there a way to only list a certain format of text from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am quite new to python.
And i want to only get a certain format from a bigger list, example:
Whats in the list:

```
/ABC/EF213
/ABC/EF
/ABC/12AC4
/ABC/212
```

However the only on i want listed are the ones with this format /###/##### while the rest gets discarded

Comment: e.g. you can check the `len` is 10...

Comment: how do i only print only the ones that has len 10?

Comment: use regural expressions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) or a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to check each element of the list to see if it matches a pattern. One way of doing this would be to [check if the item matches a regex pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

As an example:

```py
import re

original_list = ["Item I don't want", "/ABC/EF213", "/ABC/EF", "/ABC/12AC4", "/ABC/212", "123/456", "another useless item", "/ABC/EF"]
filtered_list = [item for item in original_list if re.fullmatch("\/\w+\/\w+", item) is not None]

print(filtered_list)
```

outputs

```py
['/ABC/EF213', '/ABC/EF', '/ABC/12AC4', '/ABC/212', '/ABC/EF']
```

If you need help making regex patterns, there are many great websites such as [regexr](https://regexr.com/) which can help you

Answer (score 0):

Every String can be used as a list without any conversion. If the only format you want to check is /###/##### then you can simply make if commands like these:

```
for text in your_list:
   if len(text) == 10 and text[0] == "/" and text[4] == "/" (and so on):
      print(text)
```

Of course this would require a lot of if statements and would take a pretty long time. So I would recomend doing a faster and simpler scan. We could perform this one by, for example, splitting the texts, which would look something like this:

```
for text in your_list:
   checkstring = text.split("/")
```

Now you have your text Split in parts, and you can simply check what lengths these new parts have with the len() command.